# MariaDB partitioning with char + date columns for PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mariadb, partitioning

We would like to partition an existing table of 20m rows by month but the documentation says, before starting partitioning, the table needs to have a composite PRIMARY KEY by the id (AUTO_INCREMENT) and the date columns.

Our table has a current PK of a char column. Here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE `interaction` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `tenant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `receiver_user_id_index` (`receiver_user_id`)
)
```

We would like to know if there is any problem using a PK with `id` (char) and `created_at` columns for partitioning. Or if it's better to add a new AUTO_INCREMENT column for using it in the PK for the partitioning along with the `created_at` column.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: `but the documentation says, before starting partitioning, the table needs to have a composite PRIMARY KEY by the id (AUTO_INCREMENT) and the date columns` - Could you please add a link to the documentation ?

Comment: You'd use a non-AI primary key if there was a good natural key that makes sense given its application. If you don't have one still to a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT key.

Comment: I will give it a try but I was worried about the performance of using a multiple PK with char+datetime
@GeorgRichter it doesn't say it is needed but it shows here some recommended rules for partitioning: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partition-maintenance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement for using the INT as the partitioning key. On the other hand, performance-wise, it is probably the best option to use. INT is smaller, if it is auto-incremented, it is also sequential. All of that is good for the performance.

If you do not need to stick to the ‘id’ that you implemented in CHAR type, it probably will be a good idea to add the AI INT column. Having said that, the best solution is to try it in a separate environment and see how it behaves.

You can treat it as a backup restore exercise - two birds with one stone.